# How to re-order partitions safely? Safe to use gdisk 'sort' option? Edit fstab + grub.cfg necessary?

Tags: grub, fstab, partition-table, gdisk

I have a system that used to have 3 different Linux flavours running. I no longer wanted one of them so I moved and expanded with gparted and all is well, except I now have /sda3, /sda4, /sda7, /sda8 - I deleted /sda5 and /sda6 - so I have a gap in the sequence.

I've seen that gdisk offers a 'sort' function, which looks like it might work. I can perform the sort operation, and print results and I end up with a nicely sequenced bunch of GPT partitions. I am yet to be bold enough to (w)rite the changes to disk.

My concern is that I'll need to edit /etc/fstab and / or /boot/grub/grub.cfg following this, or can I simply update-grub, to fix any config file issues?

Can anyone advise?

Thanks.

Comment: If everything uses UUID, it works well. Otherwise, less well.

Comment: Yes, all uses UUID. So I can just sort with gdisk and then update-grub to do the boring work for me? I've seen what I need to edit in the fstab and grub.cfg, but I'd rather not have to do it manually and edit every gpt(n) value by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To confirm, using 'sudo gdisk' and performing the (s)ort option works brilliantly with UUID disks under GPT disk type.

Running 'sudo grub-install /dev/sda' and then 'sudo update-grub' took care of all the tiresome '/etc/fstab' and '/boot/grub/grub.cfg' editing automatically.

Very easy overall.